# How do I archive an email without needing to select it first?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using [Gmail shortcuts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). When navigating my inbox list I can easily move up/down using:

> Newer conversation    k
>   Older conversation    j

This shows a blue highlight near the message I'm currently focused on:

> [image]

How do I archive the currently highlighted email (without needing to select it first)?

---

I know I can hit <kbd>x</kbd> to select the message and then hit <kbd>e</kbd> to archive the selected messages, but the whole point of keyboard shortcuts is to make things as fast as possible, so I'm hoping there's a single key option.

I tried the following shortcut:

> Archive conversation and go previous/next    ] or [

... but that only works if you first open (<kbd>o</kbd>) a message, meaning it's a two step process again.